# Does self hosted Nextjs api have cold starts?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, vercel

I know there is a cold start in the Node.js environment on Vercel. But, I wonder if I deploy it on a private server, will I still struggle with these cold starts?

I just want to use standard Node.js/Express-like API inside Next.js. Is it possible?

Also, features like socket connections don't work on Vercel. Will they work well on a self-hosted server?

I just want to try out new features like server components, etc., and I'm curious about how a self-hosted Next.js application works.